# SPIM Rated Torque

Tags: ac, induction-motor, induction, electric-machine, ac-motor

What determines the rated torque of an induction motor? Is it purely limited to max continuous current adherent to heat dissipation requirements, or is there more to it? From what I understand, motors should be able to operate at above 100% rated load depending on IEC or NEMA specs, but then how much do we need the peak torque to be above maximum overload?

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain the SPIM initialisation? IM = induction motor, I guess.

Comment: Single Phase Induction Motor

Comment: As requested, it belongs in the question rather than down in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What determines the rated torque of an induction motor? Is it purely limited to max continuous current adherent to heat dissipation requirements, or is there more to it?

Rated torque is determined by heat dissipation capability and operating temperature limitations. The heat that must be dissipated all of the losses including not only the copper losses due to the current in the stator, but also the current in the rotor. In addition, there are hysteresis and eddy-current losses in the iron.

> From what I understand, motors should be able to operate at above 100% rated load depending on IEC or NEMA specs, but then how much do we need the peak torque to be above maximum overload?

Yes, motors should have some short-term overload capability. That allows the motor to accelerated inertia when they are started. It also provides the ability to the motor to tolerate short term mechanical overload conditions that might be encountered with some types of load equipment. The peak torque is the maximum overload torque, but the motor operates at that point for an instant while the load is accelerated during startup. The motor could operate at peak torque for a short time due to a mechanical overload, but it could stall. If the overload clears, the motor would re-accelerate, but the motor could overheat to a damaging temperature if that happens.